# XSLT task preparation exam

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I need your help for a question about XSLT. It is part of my exam preparation.
The information given is as follows:
HTML rendering of the XML document from Figure 1. Note that groups, and staff
within each group, appear in the same order as in the XML document. At the end of each
staff member entry, there are the identifiers of other groups to which the academic also
belongs. These are hyperlinked to the start of the corresponding group sections.
The final result of applying XSLT must be:
[image]

The XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="research.xsl"?>
<ResearchGroups xmlns="http://www.essex.ac.uk/ce832">
<Group name="Intelligent Systems Group" id="ISG"> The Intelligent
Systems Group pursues internationally-leading research in a wide
range of intelligent systems. </Group>
<Group name="Robotics" id="RBT"> The Essex robotics group is one of
the largest mobile robotics groups in the UK. </Group>
<Staff name="Callaghan, Vic" title="Professor" groups="ISG RBT">
Intelligent environments and robotics. </Staff>
<Staff name="Gu, Dongbing" title="Dr" groups="RBT"> Multi-agent
and distributed control systems. </Staff>
</ResearchGroups>
```

The .xsl file I have created is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:rg="http://www.essex.ac.uk/ce832"
xmlns="http://wwww.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head> <title>Research Groups</title> </head>
<body> <xsl:apply-templates select="//rg:Group"/> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rg:Group">
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="@id"/>
<h3> <a name="{$ID}"> <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> </a> </h3>
<p> <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> </p>
    <xsl:for-each select="//rg:Staff">
        <xsl:variable name="string" select="@groups" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
        <xsl:variable name="stringList" select="tokenize($string, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name="staffName" select="@name" />
        <xsl:variable name="description" select="text()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$stringList">
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="." />
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches($item, $ID)">
        <ul>
                    <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$staffName" />: <xsl:value-of select="$description" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="$ID" />
                    </li>
                    </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I have is with the part "At the end of each staff member entry, there are the identifiers of other groups to which the academic also belongs. These are hyperlinked to the start of the corresponding group sections." Because the first staff member belongs to two groups while the second does not. At the moment, the information displayed is the id of the current group, not as expected. The first person belongs to who groups - ISG and RBT. When their name appears in the first group, the id of the other group must be displayed and to contain link to the second group - Robotics. The same applies if the person appears in the second group. If the person does not belong to more than one group, there does not have to be a link displayed.
I guess that I have to take each value from the stringList variable and make a comparison. The problem is that I do not know how to do it.
I hope that somebody can help me! Thank you in advance.

P.S. Thanks Mark Veenstra for his solution. Can somebody provide another solution?

Comment: Please state the nature of your problem. (You've made a start, which is good.)

Comment: I have a problem with the part "At the end of each staff member entry, there are the identifiers of other groups to which the academic also belongs. These are hyperlinked to the start of the corresponding group sections." Because the staff member belongs to two groups while the second does not.

Comment: Please state clearly in the Q: that this is where you are stuck (currently you don't actually say you are stuck), *and* what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next XSLT should do the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rg="http://www.essex.ac.uk/ce832" xmlns="http://wwww.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="rg">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Research Groups</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="rg:ResearchGroups/rg:Group"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rg:Group">
        <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@id"/>
        <h3>
            <a name="{$ID}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </a>
        </h3>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::rg:ResearchGroups/rg:Staff[contains(@groups, $ID)]">
                <xsl:with-param name="ID" select="$ID" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rg:Staff">
        <xsl:param name="ID" />
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ': ', .)" />
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(translate(@groups, $ID, ''), ' ')">
                <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
                    <a href="#{.}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you mind explaining your code. Especially what this part does `ancestor::rg:ResearchGroups/rg:Staff[contains(@groups, $ID)]`. I know that the ancestor axis selects the ancestors of the context node. Do you mind explain your logic for the template for Staff elements?

Comment: For the part `ancestor::rg:ResearchGroups/rg:Staff[contains(@groups, $ID)]` - it selects the ResearchGroups ancestor of the context node, i.e. the Group element. Then it selects the Staff elements that are children of the ResearchGroups element.

Comment: `<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::rg:ResearchGroups/rg:Staff[contains(@groups, $ID)]">` applies the templates on `rg:Staff` where the `@groups` contains the `$ID` of the `Group` element. The `<xsl:template match="rg:Staff">` is then applied and creates the listing of the staff members. If the answer satisfies your answer do not forget to check the answer as solved!